# Laravel deployment - avoid overwriting storage directory when deploying from git

Tags: laravel, git, github, digital-ocean

I have a laravel app where users can upload images. The images are uploaded to the `storage/app/public/images` folder which has a symlink to `public/storage`

The first time i set up the project on digital ocean I use the following command to deply from github:

```
cd /var/www/html/quickstart
git clone https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-basic
```

Development and testing of the app is done locally and then pushed to github. After any patches I run the above each time to redeploy the updated application but that overwrites the storage directory.

How do I push updates to my live site from github without overwriting the storage directory?

Please note i'm not an expert on git so bear with me.

*** UPDATE ***

Note currently i have a gitignore file in the `storage\app\` directory which has:

```
*
!public/
!.gitignore
```

There is also one inside `storage\app\public\` directory which has:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the directory to `.gitignore` file.

like this:

```
/storage/app/public/images/
```

Comment: it's already added to gitignore. I think i should be calling `git pull` on the server rather than `git clone https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-basic` to deploy new changes?

Comment: @adam78 yes. i thought you done that already. new changes should pull, not clone

Comment: which gitignore file do i need to add the above `/storage/app/public/images/` - see my updated post

Comment: @adam78 i guess you can add `/storage/app/public/images/` to `/.gitignore` (in project root)